# Circle with a complex radius

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, circles

I am studying maths at A-level, in case that affects the level of explanations.

In a Cartesian plane, a circle with centre $(a,b)$ and radius $r$ is defined as $(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2$. If $r^2$ is negative, is this still an equation of a circle? Is it at all meaningful to have a circle with a complex radius?

Comment: I don't think that's possible... :/

Comment: What is 'A-level'?

Comment: In the "plane" where you allow the coordinates to be complex (i.e. they have the form $(x_1 + x_2i, y_1 + y_2i)$, where $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2$ are real), then your equation makes perfect sense for a negative $r^2$ term, or even a complex one. In fact, in that setting, the different cases are for all practical intents and purposes indistinguishable. The only special case would be if $r^2 = 0$.

Comment: @Arthur `In a Cartesian plane` coordinates are usually not complex. And if $x,y,a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ then any equation $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2 \lt 0$ defines the empty set.

Comment: This is the imaginary circle.